# How to close FILE* opened by _wfopen?

Tags: c++, c

What's the counter part of _wfopen? I found that there is fclose related to fopen, but it seems there is no _wfclose.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would say `fclose()`, since you don't actually need anything "wide" in order to close it.

Answer (score 10):

`fclose()`.

Yup, it's that simple.  It's just a file handle under the hood.

Answer (score 5):

Use the normal `fclose` to close the handle. `_wfopen` only opens "wide character" - you will get the same handle back from it as `fopen`.

Answer (score 5):

if you check here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb(VS.71).aspx

_wfopen is a wide-character version of fopen, which means that the stream opened will be the same.

therefore you can use fclose (or even _fcloseall) to close it ^^